# error C2375: : redefinition; different linkage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am compiling a solution written for vs2012, I'm using vs2013 and getting redefinition errors such as:

```
21>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\math.h(494): error
C2375: 'fmax' : redefinition; different linkage
```

It turns out that several declarations were added to math.h and other headers in vs2013 that conflict with declarations in the libs I am trying to compile, is there an easier way to deal with this than renaming these throughout the code?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Looks like you have wrong settings for your linking stage.

Comment: 2013 added some c99 support (even 15 year have not passed). This includes fmax among other things. You should not redeclare standard functions. Among possible solutions are: use `#include <cmath>`, put your own function to a namespace, or both.

Comment: n.m. - thanks, cmath my work.